# What is the most efficient SQL query to Append Data to a master table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a master table with ~400M records, on a weekly basis I append ~1.5M records to the table.

I am currently using a simple INSERT INTO query, but i'm not sure if that's the most efficient.
For example:

```
Insert INTO MasterTbl Select * FROM NewData
```

It would take hours just to insert this one table.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into table partitioning?

Comment: what does your current code look like?

Comment: Are you using Enterprise edition?  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/

Comment: Run your job more often and insert fewer records each time.

Comment: Assuming that your new data is sequenced, and that first record from each load is sequenced after the last record from the previous load, then you may want to use partition switching.  It requires Enteprise Edition.
Take a look at this article and tell me if it's doable.  If not, there are some other simpler, but potentially less effective tactics.
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/best-practices-table-partitioning-merging-boundary-points/

Comment: I'm on SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: I haven't looked into Partitioning yet, I'll give it a try. Unfortunately 'tries' takes hours fro it to run!

Comment: I recommend you take a look at `MasterTbl` for anything that will slow down an insert, such as indexes, constraints (e.g. unique, foreign key), and triggers. Also, check if other processes or users are slowing you down with concurrent reads and/or writes. Really, if you insert the ~1.5M `NewData` rows into a fresh table (no constraints, no existing records), the insert should finish easily under thirty seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic bullet that fits every situation. Here's are something that I've tried in teh past:

1. Use `BULK INSERT`, which bypasses the transaction log. See Robert Sheldon's [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/).
2. Drop all indices prior to the insert operation. You can recreate them after.
3. Minimize logging, also covered by [Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I've used `BULK INSERT` to upload the file from .txt to a temp table which took just under 10mins for 1.4M record. From there, I used the `INSERT INTO MasterTable` from the temp table.. this part took the 2.5hrs which i'm hoping to optimize

Comment: How about `BULK INSERT` straight to your MasterTable?

Comment: If I `BULK INSERT` directly to the Mastertable it still takes the 2.5hrs. I use a blank temp table so I can run a few check procedures on the data before I append to the master.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use Partition table. On a weekly basis run a stored procedure that will create a new partition based on date.
I had a scenario where I had to delete millions of rows so I used partition table to efficiently delete it. In your case on a weekly basis you will switch out a partition table to the master table.

Here is the stored proc I used to run to take care of my partition, you could come up with something similar.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[RollingTablePartitionWorkTableType] AS TABLE
(
      [PartitionDate] [DATE] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      [Operation] [varchar](3) NULL  -- add, del, nop
)


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessPartitionWorkTable]
@PartitionTable SYSNAME,  
@TableSchema SYSNAME,
@PartitionWorkTable [dbo].[RollingTablePartitionWorkTableType] READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @PartitionDate date, @Operation VARCHAR(3);

    DECLARE PartitionWorkTableCursor CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT PartitionDate, Operation FROM @PartitionWorkTable ORDER BY PartitionDate ASC;
    OPEN PartitionWorkTableCursor;

    DECLARE @IsAdded bit = 0;
    DECLARE @DateString NVARCHAR(100);

    FETCH NEXT FROM PartitionWorkTableCursor 
    INTO @PartitionDate,  @Operation;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @DateString = '''' + cast(@PartitionDate as NVARCHAR(100)) + '''';

        IF @Operation = 'add'
        BEGIN
            SET @IsAdded = 1; -- Changing the retention period will cause partitons to be added and merged. This flag is set to avoid deleting data during partition merge.
            SET @sql = N'ALTER PARTITION SCHEME ' + @PartitionTable + N'_RPScheme NEXT USED [PRIMARY];'
            exec ( @sql );
            SET @sql = N'ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ' + @PartitionTable + N'_RPFunction () SPLIT RANGE (' + @DateString + ');';
            exec ( @sql );
        END
        ELSE IF @Operation = 'del'
        BEGIN
            IF  @IsAdded = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @PartitionTable + N'_Delete;'
                EXEC ( @sql );
                SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @PartitionTable + '  SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO ' + @PartitionTable + N'_Delete;';
                EXEC ( @sql );
                SET @sql = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @PartitionTable + N'_Delete;'
                EXEC ( @sql );
            END
            SET @sql = N'ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ' + @PartitionTable + N'_RPFunction () MERGE RANGE (' + @DateString + ');';
            exec ( @sql );
            IF  @IsAdded = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @PartitionTable + '  SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO ' + @PartitionTable + N'_Delete;';
                EXEC ( @sql );
                SET @sql = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @PartitionTable + N'_Delete;'
                EXEC ( @sql );
            END
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM PartitionWorkTableCursor 
        INTO @PartitionDate,  @Operation;
    END;
    CLOSE PartitionWorkTableCursor;
    DEALLOCATE PartitionWorkTableCursor;

RETURN 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I will do my homework and see if this solution will work.